# How do I fix "discord.NotFound"

Tags: discord.py

This is my first question ever on Stackoverflow, so if I screw up, let me know and I'll either edit this post, or take it down. Anyways I made an emojiinfo command, and thee is an error on line 8, and that is; `except discord.NotFound:`.

Heres my code;

```py
@client.command(aliases=['ei','emoji'])
async def emojiinfo(self, ctx, emoji: discord.Emoji = None):
    if not emoji:
        return await ctx.invoke(self.bot.get_command('help'), entity='emojiinfo')

    try:
        emoji= await emoji.guild.fetch_emoji(emoji.id)
    exept discord.NotFound:
        return await ctx.send("I could not find this emoji.")
    
    is_managed = 'Yes' if emoji.managed else 'No'
    is_animated = 'Yes' if emoji.animated else 'No'
    requires_colons = 'Yes' if emoji.requires_colons else 'No'
    creaton_time = emoji.created_at.strftime('%I:% %p %B %d, %Y')
    can_use_emoji= 'Everyone' if not emoji.roles else ' '.join(role.name for role in emoji.roles)

    description = f'''
    **General;**
    **- Name: {emoji.name}
    **- ID:** {emoji.id}
    **- URL:** [Link To Emoji]({emoji.url})
    **- Author:** {emoji.user.mention}
    **- Time Created:** {creaton_time}
    **- Usable By:** {can_use_emoji}

    **Other;**
    **- Animated:** {is_animated}
    **- Managed:** {is_managed}
    **- Requires Colons:** {requires_colons}
    **- Guild Name** {emoji.guild.name}
    '''

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'**Emoji information for:** {emoji.name}', description=description, color=discord.Color.from_rgb(61, 31, 103))
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=emoji.url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If you could reply with what I need to fix it, or a fixed version of my code..that'd be great! Thank you!

Comment: You wrote `exept`

Comment: wow- okay, I am just- bewildered at that..I am really blind..jeez. Thanks!